# Creating a Class Attribute dependent on Another Attribute

Tags: python-2.7, class, properties, pygame

I am currently working on a small RPG in Pygame to get used to object oriented coding.

When looking into how to auto-update a property I came across the following:

```
class P:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

I tried applying it to my code but I get the following error:

```
  File "weapons.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.name = '{} {}'.format(ammo, self.raw_name)

TypeError: name() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I understand what the error is but I don't get how to solve it since I need both the raw_name and the ammo attributes to auto-update my Arrow instance's name.

My class is as such:

```
class Projectile(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, value, image, x, y, speed, dmg, dmg_modif, ammo):
        super(Projectile, self).__init__(name, value, image, x, y)
        self.dest = (self.rect[0],self.rect[1])
        self.speed = speed
        self.dmg_modif = dmg_modif
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.orientation = 0
        self.ammo = ammo

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.___name  


    @name.setter
    def name(self, raw_name, ammo):
        if '{} {}'.format(raw_name,ammo) != self.___name:
            self.___name = '{} {}'.format(raw_name,ammo)
```

The child class which returns the error is:

```
class Arrow(Projectile):
    def __init__(self, ammo): #name, value, image, x, y, dmg
        self.raw_name = 'Arrows'
        self.name = '{} {}'.format(ammo, self.raw_name)
        self.value = 5
        self.image = variables.quiver_img
        self.speed = 4
        self.dmg = 2
        self.dmg_modif = 1
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(self.name, self.value, self.image, 200, 150, self.speed, self.dmg, self.dmg_modif, ammo)
```

And the parent classes are, Item and MySprite:

```
class Item(MySprite):

    def __init__(self, name, value, image, x, y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Item, self).__init__(image, x, y)

        self.name = name
        self.value = value 
        self.inv_pos = -1
```

and

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image,x,y):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(MySprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y) #initial placement
        self.top_cp = (self.rect[0]+self.rect[2]/2,self.rect[1])
        self.bot_cp = (self.top_cp[0],self.rect[1]+self.rect[3])
        self.left_cp = (self.rect[0],self.rect[1]+self.rect[3]/2)
        self.right_cp = (self.left_cp[0]+self.rect[2],self.left_cp[1])
        self.center = self.rect.center
        self.pos = self.rect.topleft
        self.blit_order = 1
        self.level =  variables.current_level #Level(1)#level to which sprite belongs
```

Any help would be welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually managed to solve my problem:

```
class Projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, raw_name, ammo):
        self.raw_name = raw_name
        self.name = self.raw_name
        self.ammo = ammo

    @property
    def ammo(self):
        return self._ammo

    @ammo.setter
    def ammo(self, ammo):
        self.name = str(ammo) + self.raw_name
        self._ammo = ammo


class Arrow(Projectile):

    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_name = ' Arrows'
        self.name = self.raw_name
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(self.raw_name, ammo
        = 10)

arrow = Arrow()
print arrow.ammo 
print arrow.name 
arrow.ammo = 15
print arrow.ammo 
print arrow.name
```

gives:

```
>>>10
>>>10 Arrows
>>>15
>>>15 Arrows
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.

Your code looks a little complicated. OK, the first problem is that you can't pass multiple arguments to a setter. You can either pass a tuple or just use a traditional setter method `def set_name(self, name, ammo):`.

Another problem is that you use the `___name` attribute before it has been set, for example in the second line of the `Arrow`s `__init__` method.

Private attributes should have one underscore not three (that's just a convention to warn other programmers). If you have two or more underscores than the name gets [mangled](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Also, it looks to me like you change the name in the setter only if the new name is equal to the old name (kinda pointless ;)). What do you actually want to do there? Maybe you don't need properties at all.

Here's a fixed (minimal) version of your code:

```
import pygame


class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MySprite, self).__init__()


class Item(MySprite):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Item, self).__init__()
        self.name = name


class Projectile(Item):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Projectile, self).__init__(name)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name + ' foo'


class Arrow(Projectile):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(name='Arrows')

arrow = Arrow()
print(arrow.name)
arrow.name = 'New name'
print(arrow.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will try that tonight. Basically what I hope to achieve is that every time the "ammo" count is changed the name get's changed. The reason for that is that I display the name in the player's inventory. So if the player has 10 arrows I want the name to be "10 Arrows", if for whatever reason an arrow is removed (i.e ammo -= 1) then the name updates to "9 Arrows" etc... I've managed to do it, but it is tedious as I have to find every potential places in the game where the arrow ammo can be changed and then add a line to rename the instance.

Comment: You are right here : (kinda pointless ;). I meant different, I edited the question. Also, with one or two underscores prior to the name I had the error _classname__spam doesn't exist, that's why I put 3 underscores.